# Start Spring Boot App from other application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception

I have a java application and a Spring Boot application. I want to `MySpringBootApp.run()` and `MySpringBootApp.hereYouHaveSomeInfo()`, so I want to call methods of the Spring Boot App but Spring Boot kind of processes my class and renames it, so I get a ClassNotFoundException in the other App.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: you did remove the answer hook, may I ask you for a reason?

Comment: Because what I wanted is to load my Spring Boot App as a plugin from within another application (e.g. call the main method manually), but this is not possible with the method described below, since a custom packaging method is needed and I don‘t need the .original Jar file as a dependency.

Comment: You should have told earlier. Is your problem still valid?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are building the executable version of the spring boot application.

This jar file cannot be used as a dependency.

You need to build the classical jar file without the dependencies and add this to your application's dependency list.

I suppose you build with `maven`. The `target` folder will contain two files:

- a `yourapp-<version>.jar` and
- a `yourapp-<version>.jar.original` which is substanially smaller.

The .jar File is not suitable for inclusion as a dependency. You need the .original file. I suggest, if you need both, that you setup a project creating the .original file as regular .jar target, without the spring-boot plugin. And you add another project, with the spring-boot plugin, that requires the "simple" .jar file as dependency and has the spring-boot plugin enabled.

Your second application will also list the "simple" jar file as a dependency, the fat jar can be delivered as usual.